# flutter StreamBuilder showing error when i run it

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to fetch data from my api with `StreamBuilder` here is what i do

```
 loadProduct(String categoryId, int limit, int offset) async {
    fetchProducts(http.Client(), categoryId, limit, offset).then((res) async {
      return res;
    });
  }

  static List<Products> parseProducts(String responseBody) {
    final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<Products>((json) => Products.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }

  Future<List<Products>> fetchProducts(http.Client client, String categoryId, int limit, int offset) async {
    final response = await http.post(Configuration.url +
        "api/getProducts/" +
        categoryId +
        "/" +
        limit.toString() +
        "/" +
        offset.toString());
    if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 300) {
      throw new Exception('Failed to fetch data');
    } else {
      return compute(parseProducts, response.body);
    }
  }
```

and here is how i use it

```
 Flexible(
                  child: StreamBuilder<List<Products>>(
                stream: _productController.stream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  print(snapshot.connectionState);
                  if (snapshot.connectionState.toString() ==
                      "ConnectionState.done") {
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return errMess(context, "Failed to fetch data");
                    } else {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        if (snapshot.data.length > 0) {
                          return ProductList(category: snapshot.data);
                        } else {
                          return errMess(context,
                              "There is no available product in this category");
                        }
                      } else {
                        return errMess(context,
                            "There is no available product in this category");
                      }
                    }
                  } else {
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
                },
              )),
```

when i run it i get this error

```
I/flutter (26535): Another exception was thrown: type '_ControllerStream<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<List<Products>>'
```

my full code https://gist.github.com/bobykurniawan11/6318018d0afc7395213c3e0604d5aab2

how i can fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things:

If you are using a stream to display the list of products you would need to add items to that stream.

```
loadProduct(String categoryId, int limit, int offset) async {
   List<Product> products = await fetchProducts(http.Client(), categoryId, limit, offset);
   _productController.sink.add(products);
}
```

The other thing is typing your StreamController.

```
  StreamController<List<Product>> _productController = new StreamController<List<Product>>();
```

PS: Extra tip

You can check equality with enums (Less error prone)  ;)

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
```

---

You can simplify your builder function as you don't really need the connection state:

```
if (snapshot.hasError) {
     return errMess(context, "Failed to fetch data");
}else if (snapshot.hasData){   
    if (snapshot.data.isNotEmpty) {
        return ProductList(category: snapshot.data);
    } else {
        return errMess(context,
            "There is no available product in this category");
    }
}else{
    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
}
```

Comment: thanks, the error is gone, but why the connection state stuck on `ConnectionState.active`?

Comment: You can change your logic in the builder: I will update the answer

Comment: one thing, if i re-call `loadProduct`  why the data is not changing. (should i create new question ?)

Comment: @MyNameIs Yes it would be better a different question with more specific details :)

Comment: ok, internet is only my teacher so i will use stackoverflow so much

Comment: here is the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57039229/how-to-implement-pull-to-refresh-to-streambuilder, hope you can visit it